# Get div's children values

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good Afternoon, I am trying to get all the children's values of the parent div `.clonedInput` on `.send` button click. Also I would like the output to be formatted like bellow and please place in a temporary `alert();` variable to confirm functioning code.

//Example:

//Div:1 textboxvalue1 textboxvalue2 textboxvalue3 textboxvalue4//

//New line//

//Div 2:textboxvalue1 textboxvalue2 textboxvalue3 textboxvalue4//

Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5xu5myvq/

Thanks Again :)

Comment: Is your goal to add more rows of input boxes dynamically?

Comment: No to gather all of the text field values

Comment: I'm getting a js error message using jquery 1.8, but not 1.9, are you tied to 1.8?

Comment: Your error is happening because of `.live()` event handler. You can change it to `.on`, it does the same thing.

Comment: Seems to work the best in 1.8.3, I should not be tied

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz Thanks you are correct, try updating and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get each field's value with jquery's `.each()` method:

```
("button.send").on("click", function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.quantity').each(function(){
       total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5xu5myvq/2/

If you would like to display in the format that you wanted in your question, here is the demo for that as well: https://jsfiddle.net/5xu5myvq/4/

Comment: Thanks the quantity works well, but how can I get all the text boxes values within the .clonedInput div?

Comment: I added that to the end of the answer, which is under this link: https://jsfiddle.net/5xu5myvq/4/

Comment: Thanks, any way to make quantity: value width: value Height: value special note value?

Comment: yeah, you can simply update the string to include those titles before each value: https://jsfiddle.net/5xu5myvq/5/

Comment: Thanks Again, can I have it only display text values that are full filled out?

Comment: Also, i am having a problem removing? any ideas

Comment: @ShadowLine, i believe that would be a different question than displaying your outcome when submited.

Comment: True, thanks for all of you help, But you code does seem to have a bug when removing it only allows once.

Comment: @ShadowLine, that is your code not mine :) I did not modify anything in your code other than `btn.send` click event.

Comment: Thanks Again :) copied only the .send section and now it works

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish what you want. Adjust the id #clonedInput1 to be a class or whatever you need.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".send").on("click", function(){
        var txtValues = 'Div1:';
    // Get all inputs values on send button click and separate on a new line//
        $("#clonedInput1 input").each(function(){
            txtValues += ' '+$( this ).val();
        });

    //output//
        alert(txtValues);
    });
 });
```